# android button design for fan and dilmmer control

Tags: android, android-layout, button

How to design a button like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eezr7.png) which works like fan regulator pot

Comment: What do you mean by " fan regulator pot" and what have you already tried?

Comment: I am voting to close this question for too broad  - read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the image button see the example:-

1. put this image in your drawable folder
2. In your xml add the tag ImageButton

   ```
    <ImageButton
       android:background="#000"
       android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
       android:id="@+id/layoutPlay"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@android:drawable/your_image" />
   ```